# Returning an object within a method containing try-catch block (Java)

Tags: java, object, methods

I wanted to return an object within a method that has a try-catch block. As shown below the method takes in a CSV file, reads the `serialNumber` and is supposed to return an object of the book with attributes such as name, year, etc., from the CSB file. I want to just return this object but I don't know where in the scope to return it given that `foundName` is local and thus I won't be able to return the new object `r`.

```
public static ReadCSVExample1 readBook(String filename, String serialNumber){
        try{
            String line = "";
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
            String foundName = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                String[] values = line.split(",");
                for (int z = 0; z<values.length; z++){
                    if (values[z].equals(serialNumber)){
                        System.out.println(values[z]+ " found!");
                        foundName = values[z+1];
                        System.out.println(values[z+2]);
                        System.out.println(values[z+3]);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            System.err.println(e);
        } catch (IOException e){
            System.err.println(e);
        }ReadCSVExample1 r = new ReadCSVExample1(foundName);
        return r;
    }
```

Comment: In your **for** loop **if** statement block (at the bottom just below the last output to console) add: `return new ReadCSVExample1(foundName);`. Have the return statement located at the bottom of the method return **null**: `return null;` indicating the serial number was not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move the `foundName` outside the `try-catch` block like so:

```
public static ReadCSVExample1 readBook(String filename, String serialNumber){
       String foundName = "";
        try{
            String line = "";
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
            
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                String[] values = line.split(",");
                for (int z = 0; z<values.length; z++){
                    if (values[z].equals(serialNumber)){
                        System.out.println(values[z]+ " found!");
                        foundName = values[z+1];
                        System.out.println(values[z+2]);
                        System.out.println(values[z+3]);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            System.err.println(e);
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e){
            System.err.println(e);
            return null;
        }ReadCSVExample1 r = new ReadCSVExample1(foundName);
        return r;
    }
```

If it's not outside the try-catch block, the scope of `foundName` is within the try-catch block. If you move it outside, it's scope is the entire method.

Comment: Also need to `return null` in the exception handlers or else you'll try to build an object from garbage input